# Как передаются параметры через такой onclick=?

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день есть вот такой код:

```html
<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="bo_button" onclick="popup('ajax/add_ref/ref_form.php','form=pris&amp;id=1&amp;user=admin&amp;link=0&amp;hash='.md5($_SESSION["username"]).'',true);return false;">Вступить в мою команду</a>
```

Вот код javascript:

```js
function popup(link,width,overflow,max_h){
  
  if($("div").is("#popup-okno")){
    $('#popup-okno').remove();
  }

  var css_overflow = '';
  if(overflow){
    css_overflow = 'style="overflow:visible;'+max_h+'"'; 
  }else{
    css_overflow = 'style="'+max_h+'"'; 
  }
  
  var popup = '<div id="popup-okno" style="width:'+width+';">';
      popup += '<span class="closed-popup" onclick="closed_popup();"></span>';
      popup += '<div class="text-popup" id="js-popup" '+css_overflow+'></div>';
      popup += '</div>';


  $(window).resize(function(){
    left_s = ($(window).width() - $('#popup-okno').outerWidth())/2 + $(window).scrollLeft();
    top_s = 100 + $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#popup-okno').css({position:'absolute', left: left_s + "px", top: top_s + "px"});
  });

  $('body').append(popup);

  $(window).resize();
  $('#load').animate({ opacity: 'show' }, 450);
  $('#popup-okno').animate({ opacity: 'show' }, 450);


  $.ajax({url: link, type: 'POST',
    error: function (){$('#js-popup').html('<div class="error">Не удалось выполнить запрос!<br>Если ошибка повторяется, обратитесь к Администратору проекта.</div>');},
    success: function (data){ $('#js-popup').html(data); }
  });
  
}
```

Я так понимаю что запрос идет в файл ref_form.php, но как дальше обрабатывается запрос после form на php не знаю может кто подскажет?

Comment: Без кода `ref_form.php` врятли кто-то сможет подсказать.

Comment: какой код файла ? никто не сможет помочь!

Comment: еще нужен код функции popup

Comment: Вы в обработчике `onclick` передаете в функцию `popup` совсем не те параметры, которые она ожидает. Даже по количеству.